# What is the key difference between "believing" and "understanding"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "**believing God exists**" and "**understanding God exists**"?

Comment: I believe that quantum physics is essentially true.  I don't understand it, though.

Comment: @a.cooksey you might want to add _"knowing God exists"_ ergo, the differences between _believing_, _understanding_, _knowing_

Comment: Did you look up "believe" and "understand" in a dictionary? What did you find? In terms of the definitions, what is it that you want us to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple distinction I think.

**Believe**: *Accept (something) as true; feel sure of the truth of,  although without absolute proof that one is right in doing so.*

**Understand**: *Perceive the meaning of.*

To believe in something **inherently places stock in that thing**, because its truth is not tangible, while understanding its existence does not place any. Saying you understand something does not necessitate that you think it true either.

When you discuss believing vs understanding God's existence, you ought to recognize that 'believing,' when used in the bible, is proactive, and **more** than just believing he exists (James 2:19.) And understanding he exists is still just a word recognition with no capacity for trust, and therefore has less overall bearing or religious significance.

Oxford American College Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A *"belief"* is not necessarily understood or explained. On the other hand, if you *"understand"* something you have whole knowledge about it.

So, if you *"believe God exists"*, that means you have faith in him; otherwise, if you *"understand God exists"*, that means you think that there must exist a supreme being (not necessairly defined or worshipful) and you have rational arguments leading you to think so.